# How to authenticate Gatsby Site for all pages using passport?

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, gatsby

I have a Gatsby-React application in which I have enabled passport authentication with express server. How can I enable the passport authentication for all the pages for my gatsby application. The folder structure is as follows

```
app.js                 //Express server using passport stratagy
src/pages/welcome      //Passport authentication is called when navigating from this page to profile
src/pages/profile      //redirects to this page after authentication
         /about        //No Authentication
         /index.js     //No Authentication
src/components         //My components folder
gatsby-node.js
...
```

As you may noticed that when we try to navigate to profile page from welcome page it authenticates by redirecting to the express (app.js) server strategy. Subsequently passport callback redirects to the profile page and it receives the user information. First wrong thing with this approach is that the app allows me to visit `url.com/profile` page when directly giving the `url.com/profile` in the address bar (Obviously the profile page will not have the user information).

To handle this I'm planning to give authentication for all the pages (including home page, about and welcome). So how can I effectively authenticate all the pages (if not authenticated).